# htaccess inline or condition

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make my .htaccess better and easy to update in the future

it's currently

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^register?$ register.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^logout?$ logout.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact?$ contact.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^search?$ search.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^settings?$ settings.php [QSA]

RewriteRule ^about?$ page.php?url=about [QSA]
RewriteRule ^privacy?$ page.php?url=privacy [QSA]
RewriteRule ^terms?$ page.php?url=terms [QSA]
```

Is there was to make it like - this to;

```
RewriteRule ^register?$ register.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^logout?$ logout.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact?$ contact.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^search?$ search.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^settings?$ settings.php [QSA]
```

1. if abc.php php file exists, it can automatically supports /abc URL and display abc.php?
   otherwise the list will get really long..
2. is there a way to make;

```
RewriteRule ^about?$ page.php?url=about [QSA]
RewriteRule ^privacy?$ page.php?url=privacy [QSA]
RewriteRule ^terms?$ page.php?url=terms [QSA]
```

into 1 line?
something like `RewriteRule ^(terms|privacy|about)?$ page.php?url=(terms|privacy|about)[QSA]`

My really new with htaccess, I really appreciate your input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: And for the second part, look into “backreferences”. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Why don't people read the documentation of the tools they use?

Comment: What do you think the `?` is doing in `^register?$`? This argument is a _regular expression_.